# How store cookies permanently in webview in JavaFX

Tags: cookies, webview, javafx

I am trying to develop a app for facebook and other social networks using JavaFX webview. When the app is closed all the cookies are removed and when it is relaunched we can't get use of cookies.  I want to know how to store cookies permanently and use them when the browser is relaunched. And I also want to know how to save web history permanently.

Comment: You can find the answer on how to work with session cookies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409138/clear-the-session-cache-cookie-in-the-javafx-webview/23470976#23470976 You can access cookie values in a same way and then persist them to carry through application reboot.