# How to load new file in WebView?

Tags: java, javafx, webview, reload

I have a problem with my program. I have a stage with web-view and I want to change HTML file sometimes, but I can't reload web-view and see my changes dynamically.

```
public void showme(String what) {
    try {
        WebEngine webEngine = webvw.getEngine();
        System.out.print("vsengine_projects/" + xoxo + "/" + what);
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("vsengine_projects/" + xoxo + "/"  + what);
        webEngine.load(url.toString());
        System.out.println("KK");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("EXC " + e);
    }
}
```

This code works, but just for the first version of the HTML file, when I change something in the HTML file and call showme() again, nothing happen. The Html file is in a local directory. Is there any possibility to dynamically reload web-view?

Comment: Are you calling `showme()` from _JavaFX thread_ (using `Platform.runLater()`)?

Comment: No, I'm not, but i can try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to clear the cache before displaying it. Maybe call the following at the start of the function:

```
java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(new java.net.CookieManager());
```

I found how to clear session data from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409138/clear-the-session-cache-cookie-in-the-javafx-webview/23470976#23470976) quoted below:

> Session cookies for JavaFX WebView are stored in `java.net.CookieHandler`.
>
> To manage cookies on your own create new instance of
>   `java.net.CookieManager:`
>
> ```
> java.net.CookieManager manager = new java.net.CookieManager();
> ```
>
> Then set it as default:
>
> ```
> java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
> ```
>
> To clear cookies just call removeAll method:
>
> ```
> manager.getCookieStore().removeAll();
> ```
>
> or just create new instance of cookie manager and set it as default:
>
> ```
> java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(new java.net.CookieManager());
> ```