# Is there an equivalent to a private tab or private window in JavaFx WebEngine/WebView?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a project using JavaFX that would benefit from something like a private tab except for the `WebEngine` implementation. My use case is that the user may be accessing a web page with a `WebEngine` multiple times within a single instance of the application. I want each access to clear cookies, clear browsing history, clear cache, etc. just like a private browsing window would work in Chrome or Firefox. The application is a desktop application using AWT and Swing.

[This question about WebView and cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409138/clear-the-session-cache-cookie-in-the-javafx-webview) is very similar to the problems I'm attempting to solve. My thinking is that a full "private" browsing experience would just take care of not storing cookies and not caching without having to munge around with things like the `CookieHandler`.

This project is currently using JDK 8 using either the Oracle JDK or Coretto JDK. That does not preclude upgrading to a newer JDK if the features we want are available.

Is there a logical equivalent to a private tab in `WebEngine` or `WebView`?